# How to avoid writing all the parameters (again) of a class?

Tags: python, class, parameters

I'm making a videogame in Python and I would like to avoid writing all the `self.parameter1 = parameter 1` in each class I'm creating.

I looked up for a way to automatize this process both in YouTube and Stack Overflow, but I found nothing.

Is also possible I'm making a mistake creating a class that contains so many parameters?

P.S: I tried this idea of using a function to automatize the process, but maybe because I'm new to programming, I'm making mistakes, or maybe was just a bad idea (I get mistakes about unresolved references of `self`, `a`, `b`, ...).

Just in case I'll leave the code I tried here:

```
def lazy:
    for parameter in parameters:
        return self.parameter == parameter
```

global parameters (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f`)

```
class npc:
    def __init__(self, parameters):
        lazy()
```

Comment: Six parameters isn't really a lot. But if that bothers you, you could always pass a single dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to make a parent class. The classes that have the same attributes can instead inherit the attributes from the parent class.

Example:

```
class ExampleParentClass:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2

    def foo(self):
        # do something


class ExampleChildClass(ExampleParentClass): # Inherits from the parent class
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        ExampleParentClass.__init__(self, arg1, arg2) # Initialize the parent class
        self.arg3 = arg3

    def it_works(self):
        """This works because the child class has the same 
           attributes as the parent class"""
        print(self.arg1)
        foo(self.arg2)
```

Learn more about inheritance [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_inheritance.asp).